# SharePoint List item ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, id

Is it possible to display the default ID of a SharePoint list in the edit form. I have used the mentioned JavaScript code but it still doesn't work. My work environment is SharePoint O365.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  // Get the ID from the query string
  var id = getQueryString()["ID"];

  // Find the form's main table
  var table = $('table.ms-formtable');

  // Add a row with the ID in
  table.prepend("<tr><td class='ms-formlabel'><h3 class='ms-standardheader'>ID</h3></td>" +
            "<td class='ms-formbody'>" + id + "&nbsp;</td></tr>");
})

function getQueryString() {
  var assoc = new Array();
  var queryString = unescape(location.search.substring(1));
  var keyValues = queryString.split('&');
  for (var i in keyValues) {
    var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
    assoc[key[0]] = key[1];
    }
  return assoc;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic is correct, you just need to put call to function in document.ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // Get the ID from the query 
string var id = getQueryString()["ID"]; 
// Find the form's main table 
var table = $('table.ms-formtable'); 
// Add a row with the ID in 
  table.prepend("<tr><td class='ms-formlabel'><h3 class='ms-standardheader'>ID</h3></td>" +
            "<td class='ms-formbody'>" + id + "&nbsp;</td></tr>");
});

function getQueryString() { 
var assoc = new Array(); 
var queryString = unescape(location.search.substring(1)); 
var keyValues = queryString.split('&'); 
for (var i in keyValues) { 
var key = keyValues[i].split('='); assoc[key[0]] = key[1]; 
} 
return assoc; 
}
```

Hope this helps...Happy coding!!!!

Comment: Hi, thank you for this solution. I tried but still doesn't work. I'm not sure if it is an issue with my jquery. Anyways thanks again. :)

Comment: did you tried to debug? is var table = $('table.ms-formtable'); object returning element? did you put code between document.ready in console after page is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

The `listID` should be exposed in `_spPageContextInfo.listId`. No need to dissect the query-string.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code snippet in original question and it could return the current list item Id in edit form as expected:

[image]

[image]

For current list Id, it should be a guid format, you could use _spPageContextInfo.listId directly:
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  // Find the form's main table
  var table = $('table.ms-formtable');

  // Add a row with the ID in
  table.prepend("<tr><td class='ms-formlabel'><h3 class='ms-standardheader'>ID</h3></td>" +
            "<td class='ms-formbody'>" + _spPageContextInfo.listId  + "&nbsp;</td></tr>");
})
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot but my code still doesn't seem to work. Quick question. Where should I use  _spPageContextInfo.listId ? I'm sorry I'm quite new to SharePoint and have used only SharePoint online.

Comment: Will add the modiftied code in the answer, please check

Comment: @ImeshaSiriwardane, is there any updates ?